# Websphere Application Server - TCP keep alive time

Tags: websphere

Where is the TCP timeout connection of keep alive set in websphere application server or where can we set this property in WAS.

We have an application running on WAS where we are getting tcp connections from the API (client), when the number of connection start increasing in Established state, the connections slowly start going to CLOSE_WAIT state, thereby giving issue in the the response to be given back to the client.

What parameters/ configuration setting can be checked or changed at Websphere Application Server level to tackle this.

Comment: What protocol is this, just HTTP?

Comment: Which side goes into CLOSE_WAIT, the server?

Comment: Hi Covener .. Yes the server side goes in CLOSE_WAIT, the protocol is HTTP

Comment: I don't think you have a TCP timeout issue, you have a hung request issue. In other words, I think you have the cause and effect backwards.

The client goes away after some time, but your request processing thread is stuck.  You'll need to determine where your appserver is stuck and improve the resilience there.

Comment: The TCP connections which are made get stuck and its a java process.